# JSF page redirect with https then it will give ssl expire error in mozila

Tags: jsf, ssl, https, mozilla

when i redirect JSF page through the https then it will move to that page but at that time it gives me error about ssl expire in mozila...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to make new Keystore file because old one is expired..Go through this 3 easy steps..

http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/#more-98

SSL have limited validity for authenticate keystore file.

After created new keystore file just accept confirmation in Mozila for confirmation of valid user.

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-expired SSL certificate on your server. There's nothing you can do about an invalid SSL certificate other than get a valid one (or fix whatever's making it invalid).